# How to fitting a curve with a point set like in the figure below

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, curve

As the points in the figure, a 'X' may map two "Y" value and a 'Y' may map two "X" value.

When fitting a curve with these points, it should ensure that first-order derivative and

second-order derivative can be calculated.

**Figure**:
[fig http://www.baidupcs.com/thumbnail/fbdd467ca3dce4e05e55b209bf6cc6dd?fid=3154234395-250528-2669431106&time=1364974850&sign=FDTA-DCb740ccc5511e5e8fedcff06b081203-2skix2HZJ0DXlkEgRMUWxxsBeQQ%3D&expires=8h&size=c850_u580&quality=100](http://www.baidupcs.com/thumbnail/fbdd467ca3dce4e05e55b209bf6cc6dd?fid=3154234395-250528-2669431106&time=1364974850&sign=FDTA-DCb740ccc5511e5e8fedcff06b081203-2skix2HZJ0DXlkEgRMUWxxsBeQQ%3D&expires=8h&size=c850_u580&quality=100)

**Edit:** Both Floris and pancake gave a correct answer,thank you for both.

Comment: You can also see the figure here:    https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=6878FDE2E655535!150&authkey=!AIKOYRVv1Pm-Z7c

Comment: You need a "spline fit" - if you have the spline toolbox, that's easy. If you don't, you need to read "Numerical Recipes in C" and do some coding yourself.

Comment: I have used spline tool box in matlab before. But for the point set in  the figure , it doesn't work. The "spline fit" in matlab has a condition that the 'X' value of those points can not be same. @Floris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than fitting 'y' as a function of 'x', you need to fit separately:

- 'x' as a function of 't'
- 'y' as a function of 't'

where 't' is the intrinsic coordinate of a spline (or other curve fit, eg. polynomial).

I assume in the picture you know the order of the points - it's not just a jumble of unsorted points? So first of all, you could calculate the distance between each successive point, and use the cumulative distance as your 't' parameter. Then fit splines to the 'x' and 'y' coordinates as functions of t.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a point in the middle of your cluster of points - could be the center of gravity. Draw an imaginary line from this "origin" to the first point. The distance to the point `r=sqrt((x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2);` and the angle `theta=atan2((y-y0),(x-x0));` . Compute `r` and `theta` for all points; if theta wraps, add 2*pi to make it continuous. Now you can spline fit the function r of theta. Finally you can interpolate the spline for many values of theta and compute the corresponding `x=r*cos(theta);` and `y=r*sin(theta);`

That ought to do it.